# HowlerJS step function doesn't update range input value on seek

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I am working on creating a podcast player using [Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/).

I have 4 buttons and an input that all control the podcast.

[image: podcast controls]

When you hit the play, back, and forward buttons, after performing their operations they call a function called step which is responsible for updating the value of the range input.

```
  function step(){
    var self = this;

    var seek = sound.seek() || 0;
    rangeInput.attr('value', seek);

    //If sound is still playing, continue stepping
    if(sound.playing()){
      requestAnimationFrame(step.bind(self));
    }

  }
```

The problem comes when you try to use the input to change your location in the podcast. While it does indeed move the audio forward, the step function stops updating the value of the range input.

What's strange is that if you inspect element after using the range input, you can indeed see that its value is being updated in the DOM. But the dot never moves again.

I've created a fiddle where I've recreated this issue. [Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeqdph0w/)

Here's my entire code

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/ShopTalk/080_rapidfire_19.mp3'],
    onplay:function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(step.bind(this));
    }
  });

  var rangeInput = $('#range');

  sound.once('load', function(){
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#ready').show();
    $('#controls').show();
    $('#range').attr('max', sound.duration());
    console.log('Podcast Loaded');
  });

  $('#play').on('click', playPodcast);
  $('#pause').on('click', pausePodcast);
  $('#skip-back').on('click', skipBackward);
  $('#skip-forward').on('click', skipForward);
  rangeInput.change(seek);

  function step(){
    var self = this;

    var seek = sound.seek() || 0;
    rangeInput.attr('value', seek);

    //If sound is still playing, continue stepping
    if(sound.playing()){
      requestAnimationFrame(step.bind(self));
    }

  }

  function seek(){

    var seekedTime = $('#range').val();
    sound.seek([seekedTime]);

    step();
  }

  function playPodcast(){
    sound.play();
  }

  function pausePodcast(){
    sound.pause();
  }

  function skipForward(){
    sound.seek([sound.seek() + 5]);
    step();
  }

  function skipBackward(){
    sound.seek([sound.seek() - 5]);
    step();
  }
```

To summarize,

I'm using a function called `step()` which continually updates the value of the range input as long as the audio file is still being played. When you manually select a place in the podcast using the range input, it stops updating the value even though it's being updated in the DOM and the podcast accurately seeks out its new location and continues playing.

Comment: Did below answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple bugs so I tried different logic to work it better.

basically prevent **multiple** `sound.play()` on Play, forward and backward.

Prevent `rangeInput` to set while we are just trying to drag it.

So don't bind `requestAnimationFrame(step)` If mouse is on `rangeInput`

[Js fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/e2jgabpf/)

```js
var self = this;
var mousehover = false;


var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/ShopTalk/080_rapidfire_19.mp3'],
  onplay: function() {
    id = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
});

var rangeInput = $('#range');

sound.once('load', function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
  $('#ready').show();
  $('#controls').show();
  $('#range').attr('max', sound.duration());
  console.log('Podcast Loaded');
});

$('#play').on('click', playPodcast);
$('#pause').on('click', pausePodcast);
$('#skip-back').on('click', skipBackward);
$('#skip-forward').on('click', skipForward);
rangeInput.change(seek);
rangeInput.on("mouseenter", () => {
  mousehover = true;
})
rangeInput.on("mouseout", () => {
  mousehover = false;
  step();
})


function step() {
  var seek = sound.seek() || 0;
  rangeInput.val(seek);
  //If sound is still playing, continue stepping
  if (!mousehover && sound.playing()) {
    id = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

}



function seek() {

  cancelAnimationFrame(id)
  var seekedTime = $('#range').val();
  sound.seek([seekedTime]);
  sound.play()
}

function playPodcast() {
  if (!sound.playing())
    sound.play();
}

function pausePodcast() {
  if (sound.playing())
    sound.pause();
}

function skipForward() {
  sound.seek([sound.seek() + 5]);
  if (!sound.playing())
    sound.play();
}

function skipBackward() {
  sound.seek([sound.seek() - 5]);
  if (!sound.playing())
    sound.play()
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

#ready {
  display: none;
}

#controls {
  display: none;
}

#range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

#range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #00AEC7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #00AEC7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.2/howler.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="loading">Loading...</p>
<p id="ready">Ready</p>
<hr />
<div id="controls">
  <button id="play">Play</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="skip-back">Back 5 seconds</button>
  <button id="skip-forward">Forward 5 seconds</button>
  <br />
  <input type="range" min="0" max="" value="0" id="range">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug. 
Bug is multiple play mp3. 
You prevnet to play multiple.

Add this code.

```
  function playPodcast(){
    if(sound.playing()) {
      return;
    }

    sound.play();
  }
```

---

That's is answer for your question.

```
  function seek() {
    var seekedTime = $('#range').val();
    sound.pause();
    sound.seek([seekedTime]);
    sound.play();
  }
```

Test is https://jsfiddle.net/h6b57f4v/5/

[reference] https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1156#issuecomment-487292193